# How to correctly type Object.entries in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums, interface

I have a function that calls functions in **descriptorsForAnimal** to return some information about animal.

```js
export type TEntries<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: [K, T[K]];
}[keyof T][];

enum EAnimalType {
  cat = 'cat',
  lion = 'lion',
  tiger = 'tiger',
  cow = 'cow',
}

type TLiteralAnimalType = keyof typeof EAnimalType;

interface IAnimal {
  type: TLiteralAnimalType;
  name: string;
  sound: string;
}

interface IDomesticAnimal extends IAnimal {
  isLivesInHouse: boolean;
}

type TAnimalItem = IAnimal | IDomesticAnimal

type TAnimalItems = IAnimal & IDomesticAnimal

type TAnimalDescriptors = {
  [key in keyof TAnimalItems]: (option: TAnimalItems[key]) => string;
};

const descriptorsForAnimal: TAnimalDescriptors = {
  name: (nameProp) => `Animal's name is ${nameProp}`,
  type: (typeProp) => `Animal is ${typeProp}`,
  sound: (soundProp) => `It can make a ${soundProp}`,
  isLivesInHouse: (isLivesInHouseProp) =>
    `This animal ${isLivesInHouseProp ? 'lives' : 'does not live'} in house`,
};

function getAnimalDescription(entity: TAnimalItem) {
  const array = Object.entries(entity) as TEntries<TAnimalItem>;

  return array.map(([key, value]) => descriptorsForAnimal[key](value));
}
```

And that is error message -> **Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"cat" | "lion" | "tiger" | "cow"'.**

Because array method **map** as value always return type **string**

What do i do wrong?

upd: you can see error here https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-pQGsFpCLq+k2IZVpWoycBAA

Comment: This code seems to be limited to your definitions- what is the code you are running that raises the error message? Or is this a failure during compilation, and if so where in your code does the error show up?

Comment: In function getAnimalDescription; in the line descriptorsForAnimal[key](value) - this is the place.
I can't attach an image. But IDE underlines "value" and writes: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"cat" | "lion" | "tiger" | "cow"'.

Comment: btw I attached playground, you can see an error out of there